# Speeding up past-60-day mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I use data from a past kaggle challenge based on panel data across a number of stores and a period spanning 2.5 years. Each observation includes the number of customers for a given store-date. For each store-date, my objective is to compute the average number of customers that visited this store during the past 60 days.

Below is  code that does exactly what I need. However, it lasts forever - it would take a night to process the c.800k rows. I am looking for a clever way to achieve the same objective faster.

I have included 5 observations of the initial dataset with the relevant variables: store id (Store), Date and number of customers ("Customers").

Note:

- For each row in the iteration, I end up writing the results using .loc instead of e.g. row["Lagged No of customers"] because "row" does not write anything in the cells. I wonder why that's the case.
- I normally populate new columns using "apply, axis = 1" so I would really appreciate any solution based on that. I found that "apply" works fine when for each row, computation is done across columns using values at the same row level. However, I don't know how an "apply" function can involve different rows, which is what this problem requires. the only exception I have seen so far is "diff", which is not useful here.

Thanks.

---

Sample data:

```
pd.DataFrame({
  'Store': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
  'Customers': {0: 668, 1: 578, 2: 619, 3: 635, 4: 785},
  'Date': {
    0: pd.Timestamp('2013-01-02 00:00:00'),
    1: pd.Timestamp('2013-01-03 00:00:00'),
    2: pd.Timestamp('2013-01-04 00:00:00'),
    3: pd.Timestamp('2013-01-05 00:00:00'),
    4: pd.Timestamp('2013-01-07 00:00:00')
  }
})
```

Code that works but is incredibly slow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("Rossman - no of cust/dataset.csv")
data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
data.Customers = data.Customers.astype(int)

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    d = row["Date"]
    store = row["Store"]
    time_condition = (d - data["Date"]<np.timedelta64(60, 'D')) & (d > data["Date"])

    sub_df = data.loc[ time_condition & (data["Store"] == store), :]

    data.loc[ (data["Date"]==d) & (data["Store"] == store), "Lagged No customers"] = sub_df["Customers"].sum()
    data.loc[ (data["Date"]==d) & (data["Store"] == store), "No of days"] = len(sub_df["Customers"])
    if len(sub_df["Customers"]) > 0:
        data.loc[ (data["Date"]==d) & (data["Store"] == store), "Av No of customers"] = int(sub_df["Customers"].sum()/len(sub_df["Customers"]))
```

Comment: Why do you take the first 100 rows of `data`? (`data[:100]`)

Comment: @Alexander `time_condition` is just a mask that selects the right time window, which is subsequently used to create sub_df; @David Z I take 100 rows to not spend the night waiting for the output but the objective is to have the output for the entire dataset

Comment: In that case I think it's best to leave the `[:100]` out of the code sample in your question. After all, your sample code is supposed to illustrate the problem you're having - in this case, being too slow. It's not a big deal, but if you find yourself editing again for some other reason, you might as well consider taking it out.

Comment: @DavidZ just updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your small sample data, I used a two day rolling average instead of 60 days.

```
>>> (pd.rolling_mean(data.pivot(columns='Store', index='Date', values='Customers'), window=2)
     .stack('Store'))
Date        Store
2013-01-03  1        623.0
2013-01-04  1        598.5
2013-01-05  1        627.0
2013-01-07  1        710.0
dtype: float64
```

By taking a pivot of the data with dates as your index and stores as your columns, you can simply take a rolling average.  You then need to stack the stores to get the data back into the correct shape.

Here is some sample output of the original data prior to the final stack:

```
Store           1      2      3
Date                           
2015-07-29  541.5  686.5  767.0
2015-07-30  534.5  664.0  769.5
2015-07-31  550.5  613.0  822.0
```

After `.stack('Store')`, this becomes:

```
Date        Store
2015-07-29  1        541.5
            2        686.5
            3        767.0
2015-07-30  1        534.5
            2        664.0
            3        769.5
2015-07-31  1        550.5
            2        613.0
            3        822.0
dtype: float64
```

Assuming the above is named `df`, you can then merge it back into your original data as follows:

```
data.merge(df.reset_index(), 
           how='left', 
           on=['Date', 'Store'])
```

**EDIT**:
There is a clear seasonal pattern in the data for which you may want to make adjustments.  In any case, you probably want your rolling average to be in multiples of seven to represent even weeks.  I've used a time window of 63 days in the example below (9 weeks).

In order to avoid losing data on stores that just open (and those at the start of the time period), you can specify `min_periods=1` in the rolling mean function.  This will give you the average value over all available observations for your given time window

```
df = data.loc[data.Customers > 0, ['Date', 'Store', 'Customers']]
result = (pd.rolling_mean(df.pivot(columns='Store', index='Date', values='Customers'), 
          window=63, min_periods=1)
         .stack('Store'))
result.name = 'Customers_63d_mvg_avg'
df = df.merge(result.reset_index(), on=['Store', 'Date'], how='left')

>>> df.sort_values(['Store', 'Date']).head(8)
              Date  Store  Customers  Customers_63d_mvg_avg
843212  2013-01-02      1        668             668.000000
842103  2013-01-03      1        578             623.000000
840995  2013-01-04      1        619             621.666667
839888  2013-01-05      1        635             625.000000
838763  2013-01-07      1        785             657.000000
837658  2013-01-08      1        654             656.500000
836553  2013-01-09      1        626             652.142857
835448  2013-01-10      1        615             647.500000
```

To more clearly see what is going on, here is a toy example:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5] + [np.NaN] * 2 + [6])
>>> pd.concat([s, pd.rolling_mean(s, window=4, min_periods=1)], axis=1)
    0    1
0   1  1.0
1   2  1.5
2   3  2.0
3   4  2.5
4   5  3.5
5 NaN  4.0
6 NaN  4.5
7   6  5.5
```

The window is four observations, but note that the final value of 5.5 equals (5 + 6) / 2.  The 4.0 and 4.5 values are (3 + 4 + 5) / 3 and (4 + 5) / 2, respectively.

In our example, the NaN rows of the pivot table do not get merged back into `df` because we did a left join and all the rows in `df` have one or more Customers.

You can view a chart of the rolling data as follows:

```
df.set_index(['Date', 'Store']).unstack('Store').plot(legend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I had never seen this before :) rolling_sum could also be useful for other similar problems I had in the past. I will try it ASAP on the full dataset to test speed.

Comment: I just tested it on the 5.66mb training data file.  Less than half a second. You then need to merge it back it.

Comment: I was working on a solution like this as well, but it doesn't seem to do quite the same thing as the reference implementation in the question. That code, when taking the mean, divides by the number of dates within the past 60 days for which there is actually data in the data set - a number that is typically less than 60. (This number is placed in the "No of dates" column) `rolling_mean` appears to actually duplicate data into the empty rows and then divide by 60, or something like that. In any case, my tests show that the results are not quite the same.

Comment: @Alexander: using min_period to fill in NaN is good if e.g. one wants to remove seasonality in data. I, however, want to use the rolling mean to create a feature to feed into a ML model. I can't use rolling_mean for store-dates not in the initial dataset, which min_period does. Therefore, I loop over the 1115 stores and apply your solution (without min_periods), which is still much faster than my initial attempt. Thanks for your help